# Grease pencil texture missing after file move

Tags: grease-pencil

I moved the blender file from one location to another and now the grease pencil brushes are not showing up correctly. I have attached an image below. Thanks in advance :) By the way the texture brush pack is the one that comes with Blender by default.

[image]

[image]